# how to add boundary line to ggplot points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotted some points with ggplot in R like this[image: Example] and need to add a boundary line like this[image: Example with boundary line]. The line need to be close to the points and all the points must be under this line. Does anybody know how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your data and what you've tried so far . . .

Comment: You can do it manually with `geom_abline()` and set the slope/intercept to the values that create a specific boundary. Or, did you want to do this programmatically--so that the boundary line is created for any dataset (and therefore you don't need to manually calculate slope/intercept)?

Comment: To jordan: Yes, I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: I can get the line with highest R^2 with the idea from trollster, but I need to manuelly correct the intercept to make all the points under the line. So, is there any way to do all these things programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the slope and intercept using:

```
coef(lm(yaxis_column ~ x_axis_column, data = your_dataframe))
```

And then use the intercept and slope value you get from previous step and plug them in here to adjust where your line must go, let's say your intercept is 30 and slope you got is -3, then you need:

```
your_ggplot + geom_abline(intercept = 30, slope = -3)
```

You just need to add this to your existing ggplot code:

```
geom_abline(intercept = 30, slope = -3)
```

Comment: Thanks trollster! With your idea I can get the line with highest R^2, but I need to manuelly correct the intercept to make all the points under the line. Is there any way to do all these things programmatically :)

Comment: You can assign the intercept value to a variable and pass it, right? Or am I getting you wrong?